# Updating Autocad block attribute values of specific attribute tags using Python

Tags: python, com, win32com, autocad, autocad-plugin

I have a Autocad drawing (used as a template) in which I have a certain amount of instances of the same block. My goal is to write a script in which I can select the object(s) based on a list of handle ID's then for all of those instances (of the same block) I would like to update the values of a (or multiple) specific attribute tags.

```
E.g. of block(handle_id=12345) update value for TAG_1 to X and value of TAG_2 to Y.
```

The problem is for each object, I have found a way to get a list of the attributes, but not specify which attribute I want to edit.

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")


Entity = app.ActiveDocument.HandleToObject('12345')
for attr in Entity.GetAttributes():
    if attr.TagString == "Surface area wall":
        attr.TextString = NEW_VALUE
        attr.Update()
    if attr.TagString == "Height wall":
        attr.TextString = NEW_VALUE2
        attr.Update()
```

Instead of iterating over the list of tags, I'd like to be able to specify which tag I want to update the value of.

Comment: Providing that you change the tagstrings to uppercase, the method used by your current code looks to be correct - what is the issue?

Comment: Hi @LeeMac, thanks for your comment! Some of my blocks contain many tags and iterating over all seems like bad practise, especially considering I have hundreds of entities. I was hoping there was a method that I am overseeing which would give me the ability to define the TextString of a specific Tagstring. For example: Enitity.attr("Height wall") = NEW_VALUE